# Hide blank rows in Google Spreadsheet based on value OR blank

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to get a script enabling to hide rows with no data or returning blank results.

I have no idea how to do this.

Here some explanations with the screenshot:

- The script **should start from the line 27**
- In that example, **I would like to hide first:
  rows 36-37-38**
- Secondly, **I would like to hide rows 49 - 57 based on column L with no data** (there is formulas in it : `=IF(O49="","",A1)`)
- Thirdly **rows 60/68/70 should be hidden**
- And if possible **the row 40 should no to be deleted** even if this is not containing any formula/data.

[image]

Comment: Try this - https://yagisanatode.com/2018/05/26/how-to-hide-a-row-based-on-a-cell-value-in-google-sheets-with-filter-or-google-apps-script/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to hide rows programmatically using Google Apps Script, you can use any of the `hideRow(row)`, `hideRows(rowIndex)` and `hideRows(rowIndex, numRows)` functions (see [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#hiderowrow)).

In order to accomplish your own needs, I have developed the following code:

```js
var startRow = 27;
var colToCheck = 12; // Column L

function shouldHideRow(ss, rowIndex, rowValue) {
  if (rowValue != '') return false;
  if (ss.getRange(startRow + rowIndex, colToCheck, 1, 1).isPartOfMerge()) return false;
  if (ss.getRange(startRow + rowIndex + 1, colToCheck, 1, 1).isPartOfMerge()) return false;
  return true;
}

function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()[0];
  var numRows = ss.getLastRow();
  var elements = ss.getRange(startRow, colToCheck, numRows).getValues();
  for (var i=0; i<(numRows - startRow); i++) {
    if (shouldHideRow(ss, i, elements[i][0])) {
      ss.hideRows(startRow + i);
    }
  }
  // Hide the rest of the rows
  var totalNumRows = ss.getMaxRows();
  if (totalNumRows > numRows)
    ss.hideRows(numRows+1, totalNumRows - numRows);
}
```

The conditions that checks upon deciding whether to hide the row or not, are the following:

- If the cell L of the row is not empty, do not hide.
- If the cell L of the row is merged, do not hide.
- If the cell L of the next row is merged, do not hide.
- **Otherwise**, hide.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I added your script 100% and assigned the button to "myFunction" function name. the script is running but I got this error message: Those rows are out of bounds. No ideaa..

Comment: @MzoSchöwenier Hey! I have slightly modified the code (added the penultimate line), so it should not throw the error anymore. Please let me know whether that works for you. Cheers

Comment: finally I just deleted the code under // Hide the rest of the rows and it worked!!! I thank you sooooo much! it takes some seconds, but it's sooo cool. thanks again and have a nice evening

Comment: and one last question if I may: my google sheet contains several sheets. i duplicate your code and adapt it for an another sheet but then I saw that the script is applying on the first sheet. So I just changed "var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()[0]; " into "var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetLocale()[0];" and was thinking that it would apply only on current sheet. But I received this notice: TypeError: Cannot find function getLastRow in object, but I did not anything to the geLastRow thing. And the script is not applying of course. Do you have any idea? thanks a lot

Comment: @MzoZchöwenier No worries!! You can replace var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()[0]; " into "var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();" in order to make it work for the current sheet :). If this answer was useful to you, please consider upvoting/marking this answer as accepted. Cheers!

Comment: Hi Carlesgg97, thanks a lot! you're awesome and it was my first script using in google sheet! I find the process is a bit long (almost 2 minutes for 250 concerned rows that are hidden) but at least it works! thanks a lot! I have one more question pending if you have some times to kill;) I let you check on my profile. again thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I need auto hide/unhide rows in google sheets base on values and get solved by the following code:

It doesn't take any long time to run, just finish in a moment. I am playing it auto through edit trigger, mean when I edit google sheet it auto hide or unhide rows based on values.

I suggest this instead of the above which taking too much time to execute.

```
var startRow = 7;
var colToCheck = 1; // Column A


function hideShow() {
  var sh=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Print Staff Statement');
  var rg=sh.getRange(startRow,colToCheck,sh.getLastRow(),1);
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    if(vA[i][0]<1) {
      sh.hideRows(i+startRow);
    }
    if(vA[i][0]>1) {
      sh.showRows(i+startRow);
    }
  }
}
```